# Selecting the next set of records from a MYSQL database table - PHP

Tags: php, sql

I would like to know the syntax of how to construct a sql query that retrieves sets of data from the database.  For example, I am able to retrieve a set of 10 records from a table , but then would like to retrieve the next ten after that based on the same query.

PHP

```
 $limit = 10;
 $SQl = "SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT {$limit}";
```

What would the sql query be for the next 10 records, given that I already have the previous 10 records and would not want them to also be retrieved?

Comment: Did you even vaguely consider looking this up in the MySQL Manual. It is in there

Comment: @RiggsFolly I googled it and wasn't getting any hits that met my needs.  if you could point me in the right direction i would appreciate it

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html hint `LIMIT 10, 11`

Comment: you're probably looking for "pagination" (also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

```
LIMIT 11, 10
```

and one more:

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 11
```

Legend:

> 11 - start row
>
> 10 - how much rows